# How to write a CSV file combining 2 other CSV rows (Python)

Tags: python, file, csv, file-handling

I'm trying to analyze some data, and to do so I am creating a new CSV file by writing some rows which are composed from other CSV files. I've extracted the data from one of the files (`oldfile1`) so it's a list (with specific indices I'm using to append to the new file), but the other (`oldfile2`) I'm using for the base of the file, so I can directly add the rows from that file, as they need no filtering. The formula for a new line should be `row from oldfile2 + row from oldfile1`. `first` is intend to skip the comment line. However, this code currently creates a hilariously large output file (200MB)--I suspect that it is looping through multiple times per row, duplicating the written rows. However, I cannot immediately think of another way to ensure the rows from oldfile2 are looped through while not duplicating the written rows. I also cannot give much more detail on the output file as it crashes whenever I try to open it. Any help appreciated.

````py
with open('newfile.csv','w+') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(open('oldfile2.csv'), delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        first = next(reader)
        for oldrow2 in reader:
                outline = [oldrow2 + oldfile1[i] for i in oldfile1_indices]
                writer.writerow(outline)```
````

Comment: it seems like work for `zip()`. Something similar to `for oldrow1, oldrow2 in zip(odlfile1, oldfile2): write_new_line()`

Comment: your mistake is `[oldrow2 + oldfile1[i] for i in oldfile1_indices]` it connects `oldrow2` with every line in oldfile1 -  instead one line it create many lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but I think you need `zip()` to create pairs `(oldrow2, i)` and then create new row and save it

```
oldfile1 = list(csv.reader(open('oldfile1.csv'), delimiter=','))
oldfile1_indices = [...]

with open('newfile.csv','w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    reader2 = csv.reader(open('oldfile2.csv'), delimiter=',')
    next(reader2)

    for oldrow2, i in zip(reader2, oldfile1_indices):
        outline = [oldrow2 + oldfile1[i]]
        writer.writerow(outline)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I used zip in an earlier step. I think I assumed Python could implicitly account for the index because of the for loop, but I suppose not. Perfect solution, thanks.